# How can I get redstone working again?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

I am making a huge zombie siege map with tons of redstone. Just recently, I tried to make a comparator clock to activate a command block. Instead, It only turns on and off about once or twice a second. I then tried a rapid pulser with redstone torches, and the same thing happens. I don't know if I have too much redstone in the world or what, but I can't continue anything until I can get this fixed. I have tried every clock there is, and they all run super slow. Is there any way to have the clock go as fast as it used to? (I am on Minecraft 1.8.8 and Minecraft snapshot 1.9, if that matters)

Comment: If you're using redstone dust to make an adventure map, you're doing it wrong.  Redstone dust is evil as is to be avoided at all costs when dealing with command blocks.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o2M5n1oIbmQ

Comment: ^ There isn't anything faster as it literally runs as fast as redstone can update.

Comment: That said, using fill clocks requires you to rethink your mechanics a bit. It mostly boils down to replacing `testfor` commands with `execute` ones, and work with a lot of scoreboards (one reason being that `execute` can't check for NBT data directly as `testfor` can).

Comment: Ok. But how do i use the execute command? All the redstone works except the last two circuits I've set up.

Comment: I tried using a fill clock and it worked but it lagged my world so bad nothing would work

Answer (score 1):

My brother and I believe we had the same dilemma. What it is is that it may be some lag in the server due to amount of things in the world or other reasons. It should still activate as many times as it should. If not then I got nothing but this problem Happened to my brother and that was it. Try and test it by linking it to a redstone lamp or some sort of redstone spawner and see if it activates the same amount of times a minute as it should. If not then it may be a bug. You should tell Mojang about it if it is

Comment: Thats what i did and it did not activate as it should have

Comment: Oh well then I'm not too sure. Hold on I'll edit my answer a little.

Comment: To me it sounds like a bug

Answer (score 1):

Place a command block with this command in /fill ~1 ~ ~ ~5 ~ ~ redstone_block -and activate it.
Now it should generate some redstone blocks.On the END of the redstone block line place another command block with this command /fill ~-1 ~ ~ ~-5 ~ ~ redstone_block   -No need to power it yet.

Now where you placed the first commandblock go 1 up and 1 in the direction of the redstone,so place another commandblock in the diagonal (positiveX) of the 1st one,right on top of the FIRST redstone block.

Then just break all 5 redstone blocks that have generated,and power either one command block. you will get the FASTEST redstone clock in minecraft.

btw....if your chat is crazy,you just type /gamerule comm(hit tab) false